# NTFS not mounting in OS-X

Tags: macos, mount, ntfs

My Macbook is not mounting my NTFS hard drive recently. It was working before and stopped now.

To make the hard disk writable, i had used the **Apple’s Experimental NTFS-Writing Support** from the following link : [This link](https://www.howtogeek.com/236055/how-to-write-to-ntfs-drives-on-a-mac/)

It worked for sometime, and completely stopped working.

Post that, i deleted /etc/fstab file, and installed Paragon NTFS (free version for segate hard drives). However, initially the hard disk was getting mounted with empty folder. When i searched, i found someone suggesting to insert the hard disk in Windows and try repair (lost the search link). It took whole night to show another sorry face.

Now, the disk itself is not getting mounted.

**Image showing no First Aid option**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Image showing the hard disk is not getting mounted**

[image: Screen Shot]

As you can see in the image, the hard disk is not getting mounted at all. Neither am i getting First Aid option. But, it's working fine in Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Paragon says](https://kb.paragon-software.com/article/187): `Symptoms are that some or all NTFS volumes are not mounted automatically, thus not available in Finder, and Verify/Repair doesn’t help.`.

They suggest you to uninstall any previous Paragon  like this:

- sudo rm /Library/Application\ Support/Paragon\ Software/NTFS10
- sudo rm /Library/Application\ Support/Paragon\ Software/NTFS11
- sudo rm /Library/Application\ Support/Paragon\ Software/NTFS12
- /Library/PreferencePanes/NTFSforMacOSX.prefPane/Contents/Resources/uninstall.sh
- Reboot

Also, check if you have any `ufsd.fs` into your folder `/System/Library/Filesystems` (and delete it if so)

---

I have a NTFS disk mounted on my Mac myself (read-only), however my `File System Personality` is "NTFS", and not "UFSD_NTFS" like you:

[image]